# how to add Ajax to the theme pager

Tags: ajax, paging

How do I load Ajax pager?
My code in custom module

```
function organization_news_page(){
if(menu_get_object()){
$node = menu_get_object();
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'uid', 'type'))
    ->condition('n.status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
    ->condition('n.type', 'news', '=')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit(10)
    ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC');
$result = $query->execute();
$output = '';
    foreach($result as $value){
      if($value->uid == $node->uid){
        $node_news = node_load($value->nid);
        $image = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => '165x103', 'path' => $node_news->field_image['und'][0]['uri']));
        $body = render(field_view_field('node', $node_news, 'body', array('label' => 'hidden', 'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed', 'settings' => array('trim_length' => 200))));
        $output .= '<div class="news-organization-page"><span class="image-news-page">'.$image.'</span>';
        $output .= '<span class="date-created-news-page">'.format_date($node_news->created, 'custom', 'j.m.Y').'</span>';
        $output .= '<span class="title-news-page">'.$node_news->title.'</span>';
        $output .= $body;
        $output .= l('подробнее...', 'node/'.$node_news->nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('read-more-link'))));
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
  }
  $output .= theme('pager', array('element' => 1, 'quantity' => 9));
  return $output;

 }
}
```

Comment: Views has ajax built in. Is the pager being generated by Views? If so, just toggle ajax on in the Views settings.

Comment: I do not use Views

Comment: Facing same challenge here. Anyone????